Some characterizations of the natural topology induced on a vector space by a family of semi-norms
Let $ X $ be a vector space over the real or the complex number field $ \mathbb K $. Let $ \{\rho_\alpha\}_{\alpha\in A} $ be a family of semi-norms on $ X $. If convenient, we may assume that the $ \rho_\alpha $ "separate points", i.e., that $ \rho_\alpha(x) = 0 $ for all $ \alpha $ implies $ x = 0 $.
Reed & Simon's Methods of Modern Mathematical Physics, vol. 1, defines the natural topology induced on $ X $ by the family of semi-norms $ \rho_\alpha $ as the weakest topology that makes the $ \rho_\alpha $ and the map $ (x,y)\mapsto x + y $ continuous.
I was trying to show that this topology is equivalent to the following ones:

the weakest topology that makes the $ \rho_\alpha $, the map $ (x,y)\mapsto x + y $ and the map $ (c,x)\mapsto cx $ continuous;
the weakest topology that makes the maps $ y\mapsto \rho_\alpha(y - x) $ continuous, for $ x\in X $ and $ \alpha\in A $;
the topology generated by the sets $ N_{\alpha;\epsilon}(x) $ of the form
$$
N_{\alpha;\epsilon}(x) = \left\{y\in X : \rho_\alpha(y - x) < \epsilon\right\}
$$
for $ x\in X $, $ \alpha\in A $ and $ \epsilon > 0 $.

I thought I could first show that 1. and 2. are both equivalent to 3. (this should be easy, see [*]), and only then show that the natural toplogy as defined in the book is equivalent to one between 1., 2. and 3.
But let's assume that $ X $ is equipped with the topology described in the book (so that $ \rho_\alpha $ and $ (x,y)\mapsto x + y $ are continuous, and we know nothing about $ (c,x)\mapsto cx $), and let's try to show e.g. that $ (c,x)\mapsto cx $ is continuous either. I don't see why it should be the case.

[*] A proof strategy for the equivalence of 1., 2. and 3. should the following (I'm no totally sure about that, but I'll take the danger of trusting myself).
Sketch of Proof.
(1. and 3. are equivalent) One can show that the topology defined in 1. is equivalent to the topology defined in 3. by showing e.g. that the former is the smallest topology that makes the $ N_{\alpha;\epsilon}(x) $ open. The argument boils down to showing that the $ \rho_\alpha $s and the vector space operations on $ X $ are continuous with respect to the topology generated by the $ N_{\alpha,\epsilon}(x) $. If I am not mistaken, one can show this last fact just by mimicking the classical argument used to show that the vector space operations are continuous with respect to the topology induced by the norm.
(2. and 3. are equivalent) The topology defined in 2. and the topology defined in 3. are equivalent by definition of initial topology.

Are you looking for a proof showing that all four topologies are equivalent or only for the statement in the last paragraph?

I edited. I only care about the problem that arise in the last paragraph (but I included my proof that that the topologies defined in 1., 2. and 3. are equivalent for reference).

If you denote the initial topology in Reed/Simon as $\sigma$ and the one defined by the properties 1/2/3 by $\tau$ it is clear that both have the same neighbourhoods of $0$. But the $\sigma$-continuity of the sum implies that both topologies are translation invariant and hence they coincide. As you have doubts about the continuity of the product, recall that also bilinear maps on topological vector spaces are continuous if they are continuous at $(0,0)$.

I temporarily deleted my answer as there is a reasonably significant issue with it. When I have some more time I will fix the issue and undelete the answer.
